# Git version control history "modifed files" are empty in Xcode 8.1

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, repository, history

When I click "show modified files" in my Git History
[image]

I see empty window with message "No version Editor"
[image]

I noticed, that If I commit some files and doesn't restart XCode, history of that commit will show modified files well. But after Xcode restart it becomes empty too.

My settings:
[image]

[image]

XCode 8.1
Console git commangs like `git log -p`, work fine.

How can I reattach repository to my project to reset it?
I have no repositories in my accounts settings:
[image]

Comment: I don't use XCode, but general advice I can give you to mirror each step you have outlined above using the Git bash console.  This will at least allow to determine whether the problem lies with Git itself or with the XCode plugin.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, bash console works fine. It's XCode problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s the bug for xcode to **show modified files** in **version control history**. You can vote your voice in [Apple bug reporting](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)